# the value is not inserted in db

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to store more than 1000 character in database, I use MySQL database.

When I insert 50-100 characters the code runs successfully. But when I insert 1000 characters it is not inserted. It also doesn't gives an error.

When I use similar insert query in phpMyAdmin, the query runs successfully.
this is the query, first two fields are varchar & the last field is Longtext:

```
INSERT INTO news (headline,date,discription)
VALUES ("hi","date","A crumbling pitch and some resurgent Indian bowling have set up a gripping deciding Test with the series lead threatening to slip out of the hosts' grasp. India had snuck ahead at the end of the third day, but were dominant by lunch on the fourth as Pragyan Ojha and Amit Mishra ran through the Sri Lankan batting. Thilan Samaraweera, the centurion from the first innings, held firm and is key to Sri Lanka's fortunes as they try to build a lead that is competitive enough to give their spinners a chance. ")
```

This run successfully in phpMyAdmin

But when I try to run it in PHP, then it can't run.

Here is the PHP code:

```
 $insert = "INSERT INTO news (headline,date,discription)
 VALUES ('".$_POST['headline']."','".$_POST['date5']."','".$_POST['discription']."')";
 $add_news = mysql_query($insert);
```

& this code is use in  tag

```
<textarea rows="2" cols="2" style="overflow: scroll; height: 90px; width: 635px;" name="discription"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://mysql_real_escape_string) function before your string variables eg:

```
mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['discription'])
```

This could be most likely because the text contains single quotes which should be escaped.

> mysql_real_escape_string  — Escapes
>   special characters in a string for use
>   in an SQL statement

Your code should look like this:

```
$headline = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['headline']);
$description= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['discription']);
$date= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['date5']);

$insert = "INSERT INTO news (headline,date,discription) VALUES ('".$headline."','".$date."','".$description."')";
$add_news = mysql_query($insert) or die(mysql_error());
```

Note that addition of `or die(mysql_error()` at the end, this would tell you if there is any error in the query itself.

Comment: Also make sure you are catching errors somehow, because I saw (Sri Lanka's) word in your query, and if you didn't escape it it would certainly give an error.

Comment: @Pratikg88 Note that addition of `or die(mysql_error())` at the end, this would reveal **very sensitive information** to a malicious user. use `or trigger_error(mysql_error().$insert)` statement instead and turn displaying errors off on the production site

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: I made him add it just to check what could be the problem in query and yes agreed it should be disabled after getting live (assumed) or using outputting the less sensitive message like you said.

Comment: error tracking shouldn't be disabled after getting live. actually, possible error message is 1000 times more important on a live site. that's why trigger_error() should be always used.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Agreed again.